# Array initialization at declaration

Tags: c, arrays

I have a variable of type `int array[10]`. Is it possible to initialize only the last item of the array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using designated initializers (introduced in C99), you can write code like this:

```
int array[10] = {[9] = 42};
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int array[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42};
```

This feature is also available in some compiler as an extension, for instance, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).